# Automatically showing 1 part of jquery accordion on page load instead of initially hiding all parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have the following Javascript code which controls an accordion type set of divs.
The set of divs is built this way:

```
<h1>click here to show next div</h1>
<div>text to show</div>
<h1>click here to show next div</h1>
<div>text to show</div>
<h1>click here to show next div</h1>
<div>text to show</div>
```

I assume you all know how an accordion works. H1 tag is the trigger onclick which shows the next div but hides all other divs.

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
  toggler();
});
function toggler() {

$('.trigger').click( function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('trigger_active') ) {
        $(this).next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).removeClass('trigger_active');
    } else {
        $('.trigger_active').next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('fast');
        $('.trigger_active').removeClass('trigger_active');
        $(this).next('.toggle_container').slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).addClass('trigger_active');
    };
return false;
});
}
//--></script>
```

Now on page load all divs will be closed, which is kind of stupid.
What I want to do now is have the first div being activated on page load, so the user doesn't have to click on it.
You have any idea how to do this?
I tried to give the first div a unique ID and show() it on load of DOM, but then it won't collapse if I click on other triggers (it will never hide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mimicking a click event on page load doesn't feel clean to me. You might need just to assign the classes for your first items. Check **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/zxkYC/)** for an example.

Comment: @Dominik, I have simplified the JS method in the fiddle, so you might want to check it out and update your code.

Comment: thank you very much, looks alot cleaner and still does the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an actual click for the first on load:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
    $('.trigger:first').click();
}
```

However, in your HTML there are no `.trigger`s, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can call click function of the .trigger on page load method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  toggler();
 $('.trigger:first').click();
});
```